# Replace numeric genotype code with DNA letter

Tags: bash, unix, bioinformatics, vcf-variant-call-format

how can i replace the numeric genotype code with a DNA letter?
i have a modified vcf file that looks like that:

`POS  REF ALT     A2.bam C10.bam
448  T C     0/0:0,255,255 0/0:0,255,255
2402  C T     1/1:209,23,0 xxx:255,0,255
n...`

i want to replace the 0/0 with the ref letter, 1/1 with the alt letter and delete all the string after it.
it should look like this:

`POS  REF ALT     A2.bam C10.bam
448  T C            T       T
2402  C G           G      xxx
n...`

been trying to do it with sed but it didn't work 
don't know how to approach it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please try:

```
awk '{
    if (NR > 1) {
        for (i=4; i<=5; i++) {
            split($i, a, ":")
            $i = a[1]
            if ($i == "0/0") $i = $2
            if ($i == "1/1") $i = $3
        }
    }
    print
}' file.txt
```

Output:

```
POS  REF ALT     A2.bam C10.bam
448 T C T T
2402 C T T xxx
n...
```

- The `for` loop processes the 4th and 5th columns (`A2.bam` and `C10.bam`).
- First it chops off the substring after ":".
- If the remaining value is equal to "0/0", then replace it with the 2nd column (`REF`).
- In case of "1/1", use the 3rd column (`ALT`).

Hope this helps.

Comment: the file.txt should be the input file? and will it take the all the columns after column 5?

Comment: Both are right. `file.txt` refers to your "modified vcf file". Columns after 5th will be preserved (unchanged) if any.

Comment: awesome! now if i want to it to effect all columns? should i change it to i>=4 and delete the i<=5 ?

Comment: If you have more columns and want to effect all of them (to be precise 4th and after), please replace the line `for (i=4; i<=5; i++) {` with `for (i=4; i<=NF; i++) {`.